# How can I pass 'Query Params' from a .razor page to .cshtml page in ASP.NET Core Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

**Problem**

I am trying to pass `Query Params` from a razor page to login.cshtml page. But I am not able to receive the `Query Params`

**Methodology**

I have razor component `ForgetPassword.razor`. It has a function `UpdatePassword` which is given below:

```
private async Task UpdatePassword()
{

   //The logic to be updated password will be implemented here
    .
    .
    .           
   //After user password has been updated then we need to redirect to login.cshtml page with a query param. I am using NavigationManager to redirect to login.cshtml page

    var query = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "message", "The password was successfully changed" } };
    _navManager.NavigateTo(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/login", query));           
}
```

Now when I am directed to the `login.cshtml` page. I am using the function `OnGet` to receive parameters. When I am directed towards the `login.cshtml` page through `ForgetPassword.razor`. The function is called but the message is always `null`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string message)
{

     //Some logic related to message here 
}
```

However If I am on `login.cshtml` page and manually enter `QueryParams` in URL tab like:

`https://localhost:44372/login?message=HelloWorld`

I do receive the message.

Kindly help me with this problem.

Regards

Saad

Comment: Try to remove the slash preceding the word login .

Comment: Thanks the query params are being shown in the `URL`.
`https://localhost:44372/login?message=The%20password%20link%20has%20been%20send.%20Please%20check%20your%20email`
I have put breakpoint on `OnGet` method but I am still receiving null in message

Comment: The problem has been solved. I changed the function to `_navManager.NavigateTo(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/login", query),true); `. This enables force reload to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I changed the function to `_navManager.NavigateTo(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/login", query),true);`

This enables force-reload to true.

many thanks for your help